# subtract the result of two subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables in my database that are accounts, income, expenses. I would like to have the sum of income and expenses given a specific account, and then get the difference of these sums. This is a summary example of the structure of the tables:

```
+--------------+
|   accounts   |
|--------------|
| id           |
| name         |
+--------------+

+--------------+
|   income     |
|--------------|
| id           |
| amount       |
| account_id   |
+--------------+

+--------------+
|   expense    |
|--------------|
| id           |
| amount       |
| account_id   |
+--------------+
```

And this is my current query:

```
select (t1.amount - t2.amount) as subtraction
from accounts a
inner join (
  select account_id, COALESCE(sum(amount), 0) as amount
  from income 
  where account_id = 4
) t1 on a.id = t1.account_id
inner join (
  select account_id, COALESCE(sum(amount), 0) as amount
  from expense 
  where account_id = 4
) t2 on a.id = t2.account_id
```

Does this work when I have records in both tables, so I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes it will work. Just you need to make sure that you have data in both tables.

Comment: That's what I want to solve, maybe I just have income movements for now and I want to get that result

Comment: You should use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, otherwise you will get no results for an account that has only `income` or only `expense` records